# How to handle new post from API request?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, rest-api, wp-insert-post

I feel silly for even asking this, as it seems like it should be very straightforward but I'm having a hard time finding this information.

**Goal:**
Make a POST request to the WordPress API with new post information. Take the new post information, validate it, and if information is valid and user has privileges add the post to the database.

I assume that I would need a plugin to expose a new route and have it handle all the requests to that route. I have a headless setup with nextjs and I need the frontend user to be able to add a post. I can figure out the frontend half, it's the backend half I'm having issues with.

If there's anymore information you need please let me know I'll edit my question to make it more clear. Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Goal: Make a POST request to the WordPress API

Indeed, make your POST request to `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`. Make sure pretty permalinks are turned on!

> with new post information.

This would be the information being `POST`'d, and should take the same format as when going into [`wp_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)

> Take the new post information, validate it

WP will do this automatically for its own fields. If you wished to register a new endpoint, you could declare all the possible fields, wether they're required or optional, and sanitising and validation callbacks. The API will take care of returning any error objects back to the client in the appropriate format with the correct HTTP code

> and if information is valid and user has privileges add the post to the database.

The REST API already checks this, but if you add your own endpoint you can specify a capability, or even a more in depth callback

> I assume that I would need a plugin to expose a new route and have it handle all the requests to that route.

If you desire a custom endpoint then yes, you will need to use [`register_rest_route`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) and provide the needed information.

Documentation on [Adding Custom Endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)

> I have a headless setup with nextjs and I need the frontend user to be able to add a post. I can figure out the frontend half, it's the backend half I'm having issues with.

At this point it's a standard REST API, with 2 differences:

- WP will want the user to be logged in with cookies
- WP will want a valid nonce

If you enqueue the `wpapi` script, it'll insert the URL to the REST API, as well as a valid nonce you can use. Assuming this is all on the same domain. You can then use the `wpapi` library to make the requests, or `fetch` or `jQuery().post` etc

If you want to interact with a remote WP install on a different domain/server though, you'll need a plugin to implement authentication, such as OAuth1/2/etc

Comment: I have a similar issue about sanitation, I want to change some data people are sending to our API BEFORE it goes in, is this possible?

Comment: KiwisTasteGood At the bottom of wp_insert_post() it says 
```
wp_insert_post() passes data through sanitize_post(), which itself handles all necessary sanitization and validation (kses, etc.).
```

Comment: @KiwisTasteGood if you want to implement additional sanitisation etc on the core endpoints, that sounds like a great question to ask on the site, but it's too large a scope for comments